# Receptive field TCN with increasing dilations in each layer

Tags: time-series, conv-neural-network

Below is a question from an old exam I'm revisiting.

You are presented with the task of doing predictions on a long time-series. You think a temporal convolution network (TCN) could be a good idea. For the model you decide on using filter size of 3, 2 hidden layers and dilations of 1,3, and 5 for the first hidden layer, the second hidden layer and the output layer respectively. What is the perceptive field of this model?

I am a bit uncertain on how to calculate the receptive field when the dilations are increasing for each layer, and tried to look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453183/the-receptive-field-of-a-stack-of-dilated-convolution-layers-with-exponentially) & [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265462/whats-the-receptive-field-of-a-stack-of-dilated-convolutions) post in order to come up with my answer.

I would like someone to verify that I've came up with the correct solution:

- Filter size = 3
- Hidden layers = 2
- Output layer = 1
- Dilations = {1, 3, 5}

Formula for layer $i+1$ = $sl_{i+1} = sl_i + (size - 1) * d$

To get the full perceptive field $p$ of the model I sum accordingly.

$sl_1 = 1 + (3-1) * 1 = 3$  (I am unsure of the first 1 here ($sl_0$), is that correct?)

$sl_2 = 3 + (3-1) * 3 = 9$

$sl_3 = 9 + (3-1) * 5 = 19$

=> $p = sl_1 + sl_2 + sl_3 = 3 + 9 + 19 = 31$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The receptive field is also dependent on the stride, which is not mentioned here. Assuming a stride of 1, your calculations for $sl_1, sl_2,$ and $sl_3$ look correct, however there is no need to sum the three values. The receptive field of the output layer ($sl_3$) is also the receptive field of the model.

Comment: Ah yeah it makes sense, the first $sl_i$ component carry all the previous information about the receptive field. Thank you Lynn!